# write a query in sql the company has 100 employees in that 100 employees who joined the 1st employee

Tags: sql

select (empid, year of joinind)
where from employee

Comment: please provide the schema. also tag your sql engine and what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you can try something like this

```
select
    empid,
    year
from employee
order by
    year
limit 1
```